# Clear floats not working

Tags: html, css

I have a website that is working as expected in FF 19 (when did it get so high?), IE, Opera but not in Chrome or Safari.  Sometimes it is layed out properly in Chrome/Safari but if you hit F5 enough eventually one of the renderings will lay it out unexpectedly.

Here is the link http://www.spokanewastewater.org/Businesses.aspx

The left sidebar is `float:left`, the content is all in a div with `display:inline-block` and all 3 link lists are `float:left` so then at "the Role of Industry" it has a `<br style="clear:both" />` before it.  Yet sometimes chrome/safari likes to put the paragraph above the "important links" section??  Is this something to do with webkit rendering??  It's odd that it is only broken sometimes and hitting f5 enough breaks it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a `br` to control `clear`. Change your `br` to be something more appropriate (a `div` realistically):

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

Making that change using the dev tools in Chrome on your site rectifies the issue.

Comment: Thanks!  Wonder why that caused such an issue?  They are both block level elements with no visual rendering.  Anyhow it does work, i'll accept as answer in 9 mins. :-)

Comment: @CoreyBlair Different browsers treat them differently :. Just like `hr` tags, try styling one of those and check it out in different browsers, the results are unexpected!

Answer (score 0):

Using extra markup for clearing floats in this day and age is pretty archaic.  There are 2 widely accepted techniques for clearing floats that don't require additional markup.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/qDjdr

Overflow:

```
.parent {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Micro Clearfix:

http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

```
.parent:before,
.parent:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.parent:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.parent {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```